# How to create a shortcut to start a Windows application with Wine?

Tags: windows, wine, shortcuts

How do I create a shortcut to start a Windows application with Wine?

For example I have Notepad++:

```
/media/DATA/Progs/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

and I would like to have a shortcut to it on the desktop.

Comment: Here is my explanation how to work a desktop shortcut: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut/1437386#1437386

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right click on your Desktop and then select Create Launcher.
  [image]
- Then enter the name and in command box enter the path of your wine application.
  [image]
- Now you can simply click the launcher in your Desktop to open your wine application.
- Also have a look at this **[link](http://jaypeeonline.net/tips-tricks/create-wine-application-shortcuts-ubuntu/)**.

Comment: Right-clicking my ubuntu desktop does not present a create launcher menu, only create new folder, create new document.

Comment: this does not work with 13.10 at least - there is no such right-click option.

Comment: For new versions of Ubuntu which no longer have the `Create Launcher` option, instructions on how to create a launcher can be found here : http://askubuntu.com/a/139530/14601

Answer (score 11):

WLCreator is a Python program (script) that creates Linux desktop launchers for Windows programs (using Wine).

**Usage**

WLCreator will try to extract icons from exe file, and to search for all ico files in exe's directory and its subdirectories, and to convert them to png files. Additionally, it will search for png files in application's main directory. After that, the user is presented with a graphical interface where he/she can choose the icon and launcher's name.

The program can also be integrated in Nautilus (as nautilus-script). This makes easy creation of launchers even easier!

You’ll need to ensure you have python-qt4, icoutils, and imagemagick installed to get full use of the application.

Download .deb package from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/wine-launcher-creator/wine-launcher-creator_1.0.8-1_all.deb) and once you have deb package you need to double click on it to install.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Source and further information](https://code.google.com/p/wine-launcher-creator/)

Comment: https://github.com/konarev/wine-launcher-creator

Answer (score 2):

"Create Launcher" isn't an option in the context menu anymore.

Here's what i do. It's not the easiest but once it's in place you can just duplicate/edit the existing files.

1. Open a terminal session
2. Create a storage folder for the launcher script

   ```bsh
   mkdir $HOME/.bin
   ```
3. Create the launcher script

   ```bsh
   nano $HOME/.bin/appname.sh
   ```

   Insert the following code without the quotes

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   cd "$HOME/.wineprefix/drive_c/Program\ Files/programfolder/"

   WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wineprefix" wine exefilename.exe
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
   Press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save changed
   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm file name
4. Make the script executable

   ```bsh
   sudo chmod +x ~/.bin/appname.sh
   ```
5. Create the desktop link

   ```bsh
   nano /Desktop/appname.desktop
   ```

   Insert the following code. Don't use `~/<path>` to indicate home directory, it does not work in `.desktop` files. I made a subdirectory in `.bin` for icons. If you don't have an icon you can leave the line blank.

   ```bsh
   [Desktop Entry]

   Name=<Appname>

   Comment=Wine Program

   Exec=$HOME/.bin/appname.sh

   Icon=$HOME/.bin/ico/icofilename.ico

   Terminal=false

   Type=Application

   Categories=Game;

   GenericName=appname
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
   Press <kbd>Y</kbd>
   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now your done.

To create additional launchers just copy the existing file and edit it in terminal

```bsh
cp $HOME/.bin/appname.sh $HOME/.bin/newappname.sh

nano $HOME/.bin/newappname.sh
```

Edit and Close

```bsh
cp $HOME/Desktop/appname.desktop $HOME/Desktop/newappname.desktop

nano $HOME/Desktop/newappname.desktop
```

Edit and Close

Answer (score 1):

I want a shortcut for [Fox](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm), so here's what I did:

```
$ touch "$HOME/Desktop/fox.desktop"
$ sudo touch "/opt/fox.sh"

$ chmod +x "$HOME/Desktop/fox.desktop"
$ sudo chmod +x "/opt/fox.sh"

$ editor "$HOME/Desktop/fox.desktop"  # Add the data
$ editor "/opt/fox.sh"  # Add the data

$ cat "/opt/fox.sh"
#!/bin/bash

WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wineprefix" wine "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/firstobject/foxe.exe"

$ cat "$HOME/Desktop/fox.desktop"
[Desktop Entry]
GenericName=Fox
Exec=/opt/fox.sh
Icon=/home/<username>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/firstobject/foxe.exe_14_128_1033_1_32x32x4.png
MapNotify=true
Type=Application
Name=Fox
```

EDIT: If you want to grab the icon from the exe; follow [this guide](http://blog.alastair.pro/2012/04/25/how-to-extract-icons-from-exe-files-in-ubuntu-linux/) or use the "gExtractWinIcons" GUI (available with `apt-get install`).