# How can I add the Nvidia X Settings to the panel?

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, gnome-panel

Is it possible to add the Nvidia X Settings to the Panel so it can be worked from there? For example to have the ability to change resolutions, change AA, AF, Vsync, Detect other monitors, change refresh rate, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disper maybe too limited for what you are asking but I think using nvidia-settings from the command line might achieve this. Use `nvidia-settings --help` or [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nvidia-settings) for settings available.

The other program you may need is [nv-control-dpy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=922956) but that's not ideal as you need to build it from the source code before you can use it. It is very powerful though and I will be using it when creating a script for docking my laptop with external monitors.

To add all these commands to the gnome panel would be only possible with [custom desktop entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21823/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-start-a-windows-application-with-wine/21825#21825) (shortcuts) to the settings you want to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/). It provides an interface to Nvidia's settings from the panel (as far as I understand).

Comment: I added the PPA `ppa:disper-dev/ppa` and installed disper but could not find how to even put it on the panel let alone run it in a gui way. Any other you might know?