# How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?

Tags: unity, launcher, wine

I'm able to locate stuff with the dash home then drag it down to the launcher bar on the left of the desktop, but what if the application installed via Wine isn't found via the dash search? I've right clicked on the application in the .wine directory and found no options to create a launcher either.

Comment: Why strip away Ubuntu version in editing?  Does the suggested methods work on all versions of Ubuntu then?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can create a Launcher item in /usr/share/applications. For Wine applications, say foobar.exe, you can create a foobar.desktop file like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FooBar
Comment=Foo & Bar
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER; wine foobar.exe"
Icon=wine
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

replacing USER and FOOBAR_FOLDER with appropriate values.

So you'll be able to locate your application in the Launcher by typing "FooBar".

Comment: Why not simply `sh -c "wine /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER/foobar.exe"` ?

Comment: How to configure Icon so it is extracted from the exe?

Comment: You can also create the launchers locally in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: @fotanus With the Windows application I'm creating a launcher for, not first changing directory into the directory where the `.exe` lives caused an error in the Windows application. When I changed to the `cd` into the directory method, it worked fine. It may have to do with the Windows application being confused if the working directory is outside of a possible Windows `C:\` directory.

Comment: The program can work even without being installed in Wine, e.g. a portable installation at any location or in some cases even a program installed in Windows itself on the separate partition (tested with Civ5 installed in Win10 from Ubuntu 18.04 with Wine 3.0). The `Exec` line can also take the form `Exec=sh -c "wine 'path/to/foobar.exe'"`.

Comment: `Exec=wine "path/to/foobar.exe"` worked too.

Answer (score 6):

To get a wine application into the unity bar, the following worked for me:

- Start `alacarte`.
- Go to wine - programs - ... (where your wine program is located).
- Move the program icon to another folder (outside of wine; e.g., office).
- Close Alacarte.

Now I could find the program in the unity dash and just move it to the unity bar.

Comment: I'm struggling with this method on Ubuntu 13.10. The problem is that when I launch `alacarte` it appears but I am unable to move (or create) any new items. Also, it doesn't seem to be installed by default, I had to do `apt-get install alacarte`.

Answer (score 5):

Didn't work out of the box for me, but with a small detail I got it working. Simply give the full path for sh like:

```
Exec=/bin/sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER; wine foobar.exe"
```

Comment: I had to use `/bin/sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER; wine foobar.exe"` without the `Exec=` to make it work in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5):

**Tested with**

> Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)
>     Wine-1.7.34
>     Foxit Reader 7

When you install an app through **wine**, a corresponding **.desktop** file is created in the **/home/ash/.local/share/applications** folder.

> **Important:**
>
> > 1. Replace **ash** in the path above with your username.
> > 2. In **Unity Desktop Environment**, press **Ctrl+h** in your home directory to see the hidden file **.local**

Once you locate that file, go through the following steps:

1. Right click and check **Properties**.
2. Go to the **Permissions** tab and check **Allow executing file as program**.
3. Go to the **Basic** tab and change the **Command** field as follows:

> **original:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe
>
> **changed:** wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"
>
> Close the **Properties** window. An icon of the application should come forth.
>
> Now that we have got all the necessary changes made, we are to do either of the following two options:

1. **Drag** the file to the launcher.
2. Start the program by double-clicking. When started, a launcher icon will show up in the launcher. **Right click** on that and check **Lock to Launcher**.

We are done. Cheers ...

Answer (score 4):

The best solution by some distance is to use a script such as [wine-launcher-creator](http://code.google.com/p/wine-launcher-creator/) which will take care of creating the desktop launcher, and also do nice things like extract the necessary icons and so on.  No need to fiddle around doing it by hand :)

Comment: why is this downvoted?  anyone care to explain?

Comment: great tool. I tried to create a .desktop entry manually, but it didn't work.

Comment: Handy.  Except I'm trying to create launchers in `/usr/share/applications` so they'll be accessible to all users, and the application doesn't seem to like that.  (Won't prompt for sudo access.)  Still, the icon extraction is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Dash works like the old Gnome2 menu did with adding stuff through the "**Edit Main Menu**" feature but for some reason Canonical decided to make that difficult to know you can even do that.

**All you do is...**

1. get the command to run the wine app (basically the same thing in
   this    case).
2. Press "Super" (windows key) to launch the Dash.
3. Enter "Main Menu" in the search field and open the old Edit Main
   Menu app.
4. If you are familiar with doing this in Ubuntu 10.10 or older via
   Gnome2 then it is the same process.
5. If you aren't then, Select the Category (aka Unity Dash Filter) you
   want the item in.
6. Choose an Icon, if you want to.
7. Name the Dash/Launcher Item
8. Add the Command to launch said app (what we got earlier)

Close the Main Menu app and you're done.

This is a bit more involved but this solution does not require any file editing.

**Important Note -** not all versions of Ubuntu come with the Main Menu app installed by default so if it is not then just go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for "alacarte" install that and the tip above will work with no problem.

Comment: Entering Main Menu in the Dash showed no results.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned you need the Main Menu app installed if it isn't there by default...some versions of Ubuntu it is and some it isn't. "sudo apt-get install alacarte" or just install "alacarte" from the Ubuntu Software Center and that keyword will work.