# How to create a launcher for a game - Wine

Tags: wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps)

I have the game Stronghold installed on my Windows side of my computer. If I run it through Wine, it works without the need to install it on Linux (which I intend to do as soon as I can borrow the disks from a friend.)

My question is, can I make a launcher for Stronghold... so that when I click it, it automatically runs through Wine... instead of me having to run it through Wine every time?

Thanks!