# What's a .desktop file?

Tags: wine, launcher, .desktop

I **wanted to know what's a .desktop file** and **how can I generate one** in order to have a Wine application displayed on my Launcher bar on the left. Now I have to open the folder where I store the executable and open it with Wine, and that's too slow.

I have done some research and I saw some questions related to this already answered ([How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps)). They say we can generate it, but I don't understand how

Thank you very much in advance! I am a novice to Linux, and I am using 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top answer in [the page you linked to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps) should contain enough information about how to do this.

A `.desktop` file is one of many files in `/usr/share/applications` containing the information about software applications which should be launchable in the desktop environment.

Note: this is for applications that will be made available to *all users*.  Naturally, due to permissions, if you do this with a Wine application it simply won't work for other users.

To create such a file you can copy-paste from another file into a new file, also with the extension `.desktop`, and just change the relevant details.

Follow the precise instructions in [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/139530/54256) and it should work.  If not, then come back and specify what you tried and what happened (in a new question).

Comment: Thank you, I just posed a new question where I explain that I don't understand the answer that was given to the previous question similar to mine