# Creating a foobar.desktop file and a Wine app icon on the launcher

Tags: wine, launcher, .desktop

This a specification of my previous question ([What's a .desktop file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448329/whats-a-desktop-file)) where I wondered how to create a .desktop file in order to create an icon on the launcher for a Wine application.

I don't understand what do we have to do with the following code:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=FooBar
> Comment=Foo & Bar
> Exec=sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER; wine foobar.exe"
> Icon=wine
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> Categories=Wine;
> StartupNotify=true
> ```
>
> Replace USER and FOOBAR_FOLDER with appropriate values. So you'll be
>   able to locate your application in the Launcher by typing "FooBar".

This is the top answer given to a question similar to my previous one, which you can see here: [How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps), but I don't understand how shall I handle the code I just provided. I tried to copy and paste on the terminal, but it wouldn't work.

In other words, I need that same answer but more comprehensively explained and easier to understand since I don't get what to do with the code provided! Please note, I have few skills with computers. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Maybe somewhat related to http://askubuntu.com/q/47775/250556

Comment: I now find (16.04.2 LTS with the Albert launcher) that I need to escape the path space differently: not `/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER;`, but like this: `/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\\\\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER;`.  I.e., four back-slashes before the space. Not sure why, but it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desktop files contain a command to open an application. It is not much more than a textfile, with the extension ".desktop". Although you can store these files anywhere, and run it as a standalone link to an application (that is: if you make it executable), the default locations are:

```
`/usr/share/applications`
```

(globally) or

```
`~/.local/share/applications`
```

(locally).

What you need to do is paste the text in your post into an empty textfile (open gedit), and change the line:

```
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER; wine foobar.exe"
```

**What do you need to change?**

Explanation of the sections of the line:

```
Exec=
```

This means: what comes after this will be executed if the desktop file is invoked. That is actually what would make the application start if you would run it in a terminal.

```
sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER;
```

this is telling the shell to go into the directory where the application is located (the backslash in `/Program\ Files` is to escape the space in the name of the `Program Files` folder, telling the shell not to stop at the space).

You should replace `USER` with your own username, replace `FOOBAR_FOLDER` with the name of the application folder. If you don't know, open your home directory, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to make the `.wine` folder visible (if it isn't already), and browse into the directory `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files` to see the name of your application folder.

```
wine foobar.exe
```

This tells the shell to run `foobar.exe` with Wine. Replace foobar.exe with the actual `application_name.exe`.

Finally, your `Exec=` line should look something like (if RedNotebook is your application for example):

```
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/antortjim/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/RedNotebook; wine rednotebook.exe"
```

Then, after you have changed the line `Name=Foobar` into a more appropriate name, save the file as (for example) `rednotebook.desktop`

If you want to use the file as a starter on your Desktop, save it there as `renotebook.desktop` and make it executable. If you want to run it from Dash, move it into `~/.local/share/applications`. After log out and back in, it will be available in Dash. You can lock it to the launcher then.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I understood what a desktop.file is and how to use the code. I also tried it with Foxit Reader on Wine. I created a desktop file that, when double clicked, launches Wine, but before Foxit does, shuts down. Anyway, I found a launcher for Foxit on Wine in the Dash, probably generated on previous trials. But I experience some issues with it, but I think I should leave them for another question. Again, thank you!

Comment: Just a remark: Desktop Launchers do not need to be executable, as they are no shell nor code. They are just interpreted.

Comment: @Antonio That is not correct. They *do* need to be executable if you use them on your desktop as a double- click item. *Not* if you use them in Dash from `~/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`

Answer (score 0):

A .desktop file is a text file. You have to open a text editor, like Gedit and paste the content and save it.