# How to create a launcher for Wine in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: wine, launcher

How does one create a launcher for an application in Wine under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?  Instructions at "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine" say, 'right click on the desktop and select "Create a launcher."'  Unfortunately, when I right click on the desktop, the options do not include "Create a launcher." Instead, I get, "New Folder "New Document", "Paste", "Organize Desktop by Name", "Keep Aligned", and "Change Desktop Background".  Thanks.

Comment: That option appears when you are using xfce desktop not in Unity. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps) how to create custom launcher for wine application

Answer (score 3):

You can create a launcher item in /usr/share/applications or in /home/user/.local/share/applications.

This is a file with extension .desktop.

Procedure:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /usr/share/applications/msoffice.desktop
```

The file should look similar to this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Msoffice
Comment=Microsoft Office
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Msoffice_Folder; wine msoffice.exe"
Icon=wine
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

So you'll be able to locate your application in the Launcher by typing "msoffice".