# Create launcher icon for Navicat

Tags: unity, wine, launcher

How can I get the application [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) into my launcher menu & sidebar 'dock'?

It runs in wine and has its own wine directory as part of the download. I've created .desktop files before to create launcher icons but I cannot figure out how to do it with Navicat & the tutorials I've found online for wine applications don't seem to work. I think it's because Navicat has it's own wine directory and doesn't use the one that comes with Ubuntu?

It was suggested that this is a duplicate of ["How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps) which I've tried and it hasn't worked. I'm not sure what makes my case different though, I think it's related to Navicat using a wine directory that is downloaded with the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps)

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer Thanks for the comment, I tried that method but couldn't get it to work. I think it's to do with Navicat having its own wine directory but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Check out the Exec line in the answer. Before it calls the application it changes the directory to the program files folder. You would need to change that to match the folder of Navicat. `Exec=sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FOOBAR_FOLDER; wine foobar.exe"`

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer Navicat has it's own local wine binaries it runs, such that Navicat can be run without having wine actually installed on a user level. 
So /home/USER/.wine would not exist

Answer (score 2):

I used to start Navicat from Bash till I figured out the solution.
To add Navicat to the menu, create a Launcher item in /usr/share/applications. Change the Exec line to match the path where you unzipped navicat.
 The solution has nothing to do with wine.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Navicat
Comment=Database Admin Tool
Exec=/bin/sh  "/opt/navicat/start_navicat"
Icon=/path/to/icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

Comment: You can also add it to ~/.local/share/applications/.