# How can I create a shortcut for running an AppImage without the terminal in Gnome?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcuts, appimage

I am using [Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with the native Gnome UI. Prior versions of Navicat used Wine, but this version (15) [provides an AppImage file](https://help.navicat.com/hc/en-us/articles/217789018-How-can-I-install-Navicat-on-Linux-) which I have been launching from the terminal. Once launched, it ties up that terminal process until I exit Navicat. This annoys me.

I've found [several](https://askubuntu.com/q/748626/254743) [walkthroughs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43972857/27457) that [pertain to the Wine version on Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29296670/27457), but nothing for running the AppImage on Gnome. Is there any way I can create a shortcut on the launcher bar (or wherever) in Gnome so I don't have to launch the process from a terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [appimaged](https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged):

- Download trial version of navicat15 from [here](https://www.navicat.com/en/download/navicat-for-mysql#lin)
- `chmod +x ~/Downloads/navicat15-mysql-en.AppImage`
- `mkdir ~/bin`
- `cp ~/Downloads/navicat15-mysql-en.AppImage ~/bin`
- Download appimaged:

  ```
  wget "https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged/releases/download/continuous/appimaged-x86_64.AppImage"
  ```
- `chmod a+x appimaged-x86_64.AppImage`
- `./appimaged-x86_64.AppImage --install`
- `export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin` - optional, if your `echo $PATH` does not contain `/home/user/.local/bin` directory, where `appimaged` binary is copied. Could be added in `~/.bashrc`
- Run it by `appimaged -v` - this command will register `.AppImage` file found in `~/bin` directory
- After some time check **Applications menu** and find out **Navicat 15 for MySQL** there.
- Interrupt `appimaged -v` command execution by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Tested on Ubuntu 19.10 and Lubuntu 18.04.

Comment: appimaged is deprecated now.