# How to dock/lock a Wine app icon in launcher in Unity?

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher

so I installed foobar2000 via wine and it created a desktop icon.

What I want to do now is lock the icon on the launcher. How can I do it?

Here's what I tried **which didn't work**

1. Double click on foobar2000 desktop icon. This opens the app.
2. Right click on foobar2000 on launcher and select Lock.
3. Exit foobar2000.
4. Click on foobar2000 icon on launcher. Nothing happens.
5. Just to be sure, I clicked on Firefox icon on launcher and no problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one create a custom application launcher for Wine installed apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps)

Comment: This might help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/579728/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating new `.desktop` file as a workaround. Launch your favourite text editor, and paste following text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FooBar
Comment=Foo & Bar
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/foobar2000; wine foobar2000.exe"
Icon=/path/to/image/file.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

Replace the `user` with your username.

Save as `foobar2000.desktop` then set the file as executable.

```
chmod +x foobar2000.desktop
```

Now you can place it to `.local/share/applications`.