# Did I installed Wine correctly?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, wine, mono

I'll get to this straight --------> I installed Wine, then it asked to install Mono to run properly. I installed Mono and then it said to install .NET Framework to run properly. I said to myself why to install .NET when I might not require it? So I clicked cancel and started searching freshly installed Wine. But there was no Wine. However I was able to install FastStone.exe successfully which ran fine after installation. Now I am wondering about whether I have really installed Wine or broke the installation. Because I cancelled .NET Framework installation and also I am unable to open the Wine program itself. Is there something I missed?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fully updated

[image]

Comment: Sounds fine . If you need mono you can install it later

Comment: But why I can't find Wine in the Dash? In my work computer, Wine is there when I search for it.

Comment: It is a command line tool.

Comment: Wine is a command line tool, you shouldn't need to see it in dash. If you encounter problems, do 'sudo apt-get update' to make sure you have the latest package lists, 'sudo apt-get purge wine' to completely remove wine, 'apt-get autoremove' to remove unneeded dependencies and finally 'sudo apt-get install wine' to reinstall wine.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/137151/how-does-one-create-a-custom-application-launcher-for-wine-installed-apps