# How to create a launcher on the desktop which opens a random application?

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I want to make a launcher which opens a random application. So I looked it up on this site and I found this:

- [How to create a shortcut to start a Windows application with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21823/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-start-a-windows-application-with-wine#new-answer)

But I have a right-click menu on my desktop that looks like this:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7e6pVd-HaLM2lVQ0ZFbllBZWs/edit?usp=sharing]

So now I still don't know how to create launchers.
Does anyone know a way for dummies?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand - watch out for answers covering your release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Ubuntu 11.10, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/147044) is the fastest way (at least for me) to create a new launcher on your desktop.

That being said, let's make a script called `random_app` which will open a random application:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

apps_path="/usr/share/applications/"

random_app=$(grep -m 1 "^Exec" "$apps_path$(ls $apps_path | shuf -n 1)" | \
           awk -F'[=| ]' '{ print $2 }')

$random_app
```

Save the script in your `~/bin` directory and make it executable using the following command in terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/random_app
```

Now, you can create a launcher on your desktop as it is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/147044) for the script `random_app`:

[image: create launcher]

Comment: i know, that what you are saying, is supposed to be correct, thats why i marked it as accepted, but new problems have come, could you help me ones more? i've added the new problem in the question.

Comment: @user211999 I believe you forget to rename the directory "Desktop" in the command, to the name of the "Desktop" in your language.

Comment: @user211999 Now, please, if you have more question, please don't add them to the same question, use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button instead.