# How to create Wine shortcut?

Tags: wine, shortcuts

While attempting to create a desktop shortcut for an app that uses wine I came up with this error:

```
Failed to execute child process "/home/fiver/.wine/drive_c/Program" (No such file or directory)
```

I have followed all the instrutions at [jaypeeonline.net](http://jaypeeonline.net/tips-tricks/create-wine-application-shortcuts-ubuntu/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a shortcut to start a Windows application with Wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21823/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-start-a-windows-application-with-wine)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create by hand a desktop shortcut for your applications installed with wine by following these steps:

1. Open your favourite text editor (`gedit`, `nano`, etc.), create a new file with the following content and save it to your Desktop with a name having extension `.desktop`

   In this example, I've chosen to the name `inetexplorer.desktop` and saved it to my desktop.

   > ```
   > [Desktop Entry]
   > Name=Internet Explorer
   > Exec=wine "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
   > Icon=/path/to/iconfile
   > Type=Application
   > Categories=Wine;
   > ```

   Here, replace the value for **Name** field with that of the target application's name. (In the example, it's Internet Exolorer.) The value of **Exec** would be in the format:

   ```
   wine "C:\path to the\executable file"
   ```

   (for CLI application) like say

   ```
   wineconsole "C:\path to the\executable file"
   ```

   (for GUI applications)

   ```
   wine "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
   ```

   (enclosing the path within double quotes `".. .."` is important if the path contain blank spaces.)

   Replace */path/to/iconfile* (the value for **Icon** field) with the path of an icon file (like *Icon=/home/username/Pictures/internet-explorer.png*) or you can omit this line of entry.

   <sup>On the left is a shortcut with icon specified, for the one on right, not.</sup>
   [image: iconField]
2. Turn on the file's execute bit on.

   Graphically you can do it by *right clicking* the `.desktop` file, and from the context menu select *Properties*. In the properties window, select *Permission* tab, look for a label **Execute:** and check-mark the check-box next to it so that the shortcut becomes executable.

   <sup>selecting property from right-click context menu</sup>
   [image: rightClickTheFile]

   <sup>setting execute permission</sup>
   [image: executableProperty]

   From terminal, you can do this with:

   ```
   chmod +x $USER/Desktop/inetexplorer.desktop
   ```

   where `$USER/Desktop/inetexplorer.desktop` should be the absolute path of the desktop shortcut that was created.

Comment: How do you leverage the icon contained within the executable?

Comment: Here is my explanation how to work a desktop shortcut: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut/1437386#1437386

Answer (score 6):

I've created a script that adds a shortcut to GNOME applications menu just by typing `./wine-create-shortcut paht/to/application.exe`.

You can find further information [here](https://github.com/thiggy01/wine-create-shortcut).

Comment: This script does the job! And app can be added to favorites! Very good!

Comment: This script is a gem! Worked for me when everything else did not! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/), in combination with wine, which offers a clean and user-friendly interface, that let you install and manage windows software and games.

[image]

> **PlayOnLinux** is a piece of software which allows you to easily install and use numerous games and apps designed to run with Microsoft® Windows®.
>   Few games are compatible with GNU/Linux at the moment and it certainly is a factor preventing the migration to this system. PlayOnLinux brings a cost-free, accessible and efficient solution to this problem.

**Here is a non-exhaustive list of the interesting points to know**:

- You don't have to own a Windows® license to use PlayOnLinux.
- PlayOnLinux is based on Wine, and so profits from all its features yet it keeps the user from having to deal with its complexity.
- PlayOnLinux is free software.
- PlayOnLinux uses Bash and Python.

**Nevertheless, PlayOnLinux has some bugs, as every piece of software**:

- Occasional performance decrease (image may be less fluid and graphics less detailed).
- Not all games are supported. Nevertheless, you can use our manual installation module.

**Installation:**

1. Simply use Software-Center to install it,
2. or refer to their [HP installation](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) info.

---

Here is another solution, that uses your Ubuntu OS based system standards.

[image]

1. Open `Main Menu` Application and select <kbd>New Item</kbd> button,
2. which will open a `Create Launcher` window, from where you can use the <kbd>Browse</kbd> button, that let you select the path to the `.exe` (executable) windows application/game.

   - You can also name the new shortcut, add a description and icon to it from there.

Comment: PlayOnLinux works often better than Wine alone, but isn't it very space-consuming, as it runs isolated, virtual disk for each program (not 2 or more in the same disk)?

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the white spaces using backslashes (`\`). Try to specify the command like this:

```
".../Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS2/..."
```

Note the `\` before spaces.

Comment: Or, you can use quotation, which is pretty much more readable. `wine '/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Some Program with many spaces/program.exe'`

Answer (score 1):

Because I cannot comment, I have to give here a separate answer. ;-) A big thanks goes to user "precise". The solution mentioned by him or her worked for me at Kubuntu 18.04 and Wine 5.0 but I had to add at the path name two backslashes (and not just one).

Based at the above mentioned example this will look like:

```
Exec=wine "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"
```

I have no idea why this is so, maybe because my Program Path is somewhat more complex:

```
Exec=wine "C:\\Program Files\\Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP\\Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP.exe"
```

A little update to this topic. Finally I was able to add the correct icon to the shortcut. (It was available in a hidden folder at the corresponding program location.) The extraction of the icon from the executable also worked but I was not able to use the separate *.ico file as icon source.

However, - here follows the full content of my manually generated and perfectly working Wine shortcut.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/franz/.wine" wine "C:\\Program Files\\Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP\\Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP.exe"
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/franz/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP/.install4j/i4j_extf_9_1bhpfkc_1iu21cz.png
Path=/home/franz/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP
StartupWMClass=Steuer St.Gallen 2019 nP.exe
```

This corresponds mostly to the automatic established Microsoft PowerPoint Viewer shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Microsoft PowerPoint Viewer 
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/franz/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/franz/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/franz/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Microsoft\\ PowerPoint\\ Viewer\\ .lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Comment=Mit Microsoft PowerPoint erstellte Präsentationen anzeigen.
Icon=976E_ppvwicon.0
StartupWMClass=pptview.exe
```

There were added automatically several other parameters (with mostly no value) after making the file executable. Because these have no function, I have removed them again manually.

```
Comment[de_DE]=
Comment=
GenericName[de_DE]=
GenericName=
MimeType=
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

Comment: Here is my explanation how to work a desktop shortcut: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut/1437386#1437386

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did on Linux Mint 20.3 XFCE:
I followed the steps made by precise but with some additions, in my case i have installed TES:Oblivion and added some mods, one of them function as a separate launcher, so i used some of the original desktop shortcut settings in the new one.

Original:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=The Elder Scrolls IV - Oblivion
    Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/emmanuel/.wine" wine-stable C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/emmanuel/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Escritorio/The\\ Elder\\ Scrolls\\ IV\\ -\\ Oblivion.lnk
    Type=Application
    StartupNotify=true
    Path=/home/emmanuel/.wine/dosdevices/d:/Oblivion
    Icon=26C1_goggame-1458058109.0
    StartupWMClass=oblivionlauncher.exe
```

And here the version i did:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=The Elder Scrolls IV - Oblivion OBSE
    Exec=wine "D:\Oblivion\obse_loader.exe"
    Path=/home/emmanuel/.wine/dosdevices/d:/Oblivion
    Icon=26C1_goggame-1458058109.0
    Type=Application
    Categories=Wine;
```

Take note the Icon line, this is the real icon name: `goggame-1458058109.ico`  ; you can see a difference there, i don't know why it is writen like that in the original shortcut, but it works.
The Path line i think it is needed to use that icon file.

This may help you also if you need a NO_CD or patched launcher/executable for running old games.

Answer (score -1):

I know the best and easiest way !

Open /home/.local/share/wine/programs
And you can see your wine apps folders open your app folder , there is your_app_name.desktop , copy it to desktop and right click on it , and then , left click on Allow Launching

Congratulations !!! Your app shortcut is on your desktop , enjoy !

Sorry if my English is not good